What does 言葉が続かない actually mean?
この待遇に裏でもあるのかと伺っている。
しかし、余計な言葉が続かないとわかると、さっさと木箱に取り付き、押し入れの下段にしまいこんだ。
In the first line the other persons/culprit ask to the main character if there is an "Hidden" reason for the way the main character is treating him so well and not exposing his crime. The text is narration but it's presented a what the culprit asked to him.
However the main character seems to conclude something in the next line, and puts away the murder weapon in the storage without incriminating the culprit.
What to make of 言葉が続かない? "Words won't connect?

"余計な言葉が続かない"<--余計 is kind of important to the meaning here. 続かない doesn't mean "won't connect".  続く means to continue.

What made you think the subject of 伺う and the subject of わかる/取り付く/しまいこむ are different? Aren't these actions by the same person? If you're unsure, please provide more context in original Japanese.

The hole 余計な言葉が続かない would be easier to understand as "He won't say anything unnecessary anymore"
